# VB5 and Oracle 11G: Init parameter NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS ignored

Tags: oracle11g, odbc, vb5

I want to insert number values via the IHM into a table with a column of datatype NUMBER.

Now when I query the table there is '1234' instead of '12,34' inserted.

When I insert directely in the DB I get a correct result.

The program is coded in VB5 and database and Oracle 11g (11.0.2).

Someone could help me please?

The VB5 code:

```
        Set cmd1 = New ADODB.Command
        Set cmd1.ActiveConnection = dbConn1

        Set v_Enregistrement_insert = New ADODB.Recordset
        v_Enregistrement_insert.CursorLocation = adUseClient

        'Début de la transaction

        dbConn1.BeginTrans

        cmd1.CommandText = InsertParamMaint

        With cmd1
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adVarChar, adParamInput, 2, cb_CodMaint.Text)
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adVarChar, adParamInput, 7, cb_RubPaye.Text)
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adVarChar, adParamInput, 7, txtFields(3).Text)
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adDouble, adParamInput, 7, txtFields(4).Text)
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adVarChar, adParamInput, 7, txtFields(5).Text)
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adVarChar, adParamInput, 7, txtFields(6).Text)
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adVarChar, adParamInput, 7, txtFields(7).Text)
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adVarChar, adParamInput, 7, txtFields(8).Text)
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adVarChar, adParamInput, 7, txtFields(9).Text)
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adVarChar, adParamInput, 1, cb_Et.Text)

         End With

        'Enregistrement de la transaction

        Set v_Enregistrement_insert = cmd1.Execute()

        dbConn1.CommitTrans

        bAjout = False
        datPrimaryRS.Enabled = True

Else

  datPrimaryRS.UpdateRecord

  End If

  datPrimaryRS.Refresh
```

Comment: Is it treating the comma as a group separator rather than a decimal separator? Oracle would fail on an implicit `to_number('1,2')` if the NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS defined comma as G, so presumably VB must be doing that implicitly. Can you convert `txtFields(4).Text` to a double on the VB side and pass that, and also see what explicit conversion gives you?

Comment: Not really my area but from some quick searching I think I'm referring to [culture-specific separators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd84bdyt(v=vs.110).aspx) e.g. [NumberDecimalSeparator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator(v=vs.110).aspx). No idea if I'm in the right ballpark but might get you somewhere... And see [these questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=NumberDecimalSeparator+%5Bvb%5D). If one of those helps this can be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: @AlexPoole I edited my post

Comment: My earlier comment was talking about a VB setting, not an Oracle setting. The problem isn't with VB talking to the database, it's the (implicit) conversion of `txtFields(4).Text` to `adDouble`, which is happening in VB, before it sends that already-wrong double value to the database. At least, that's what I think is happening, I don't have VB available to verify, but the questions from the search I linked to seem to support that.